# Declaring variables while creating a trigger in MySql

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers, declare

I'm having a little problem creating a trigger, because I have to declare a few variables, and then set some of them to 0, so they will start increasing their value in a loop, depending on conditions.
Anyway, I'm gonna paste the code, and the error that it throws, and hopefully someone will tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_request AFTER UPDATE ON medical_tests
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE y INT, x0 INT, x3 INT, counting INT
SET y=0, x0=0, x3=0,
counting = count(SELECT * FROM medical_tests WHERE medical_tests.request_id = UPDATED.request_id)

WHILE (y<counting)
BEGIN
SET y=y+1
IF (medical_tests.status=1)
BEGIN
SET x0=x0+1
END
ELSEIF (medical_tests.status=3)
BEGIN
SET x3=x3+1
END
END IF
END WHILE

IF (x0>0 AND x0<counting)
BEGIN
UPDATE requests SET status=2 WHERE requests.id=UPDATED.request_id
END
ELSEIF (x3=counting)
BEGIN
UPDATE requests SET status=3 WHERE requests.id=UPDATED.request_id
END
ENDIF
END
```

It throws the following error:
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' x0 INT, x3 INT, counting INT SET y=0, x0=0, x3=0, counting= count(SELECT * FROM m' at line 3.

Last time i wrote a trigger I did it in MySQL Server and the syntax is a little different. Maybe I'm just going to need to create a procedure and call it instead. SO if anyone can help, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First things first.** To properly **[declare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html)** variables of the same type and the same initial value in MySQL change

```
DECLARE y INT, x0 INT, x3 INT, counting INT
```

to

```
DECLARE y, x0, x3, counting INT DEFAULT 0;
```

This declares four variables of type `INT` with default value of `0`.

But that is just the beginning. Your code have several other problems:

1. You have to terminate **every** statement with a semicolon `;` including `IF ... END IF;`, `WHILE ... END WHILE;` etc.
2. To refer to columns of a row being updated you have to use `NEW` keyword instead of `UPDATED`.
3. You don't need to wrap every `SET` statement in `BEGIN...END` block. It just adds clutter.
4. You can't just arbitrarily access a column value in your while loop with `(medical_tests.status=1)`. If you meant to refer to `status` column of a row being updated then again you need to use a special keyword `NEW` or `OLD`. If you meant to traverse some other resultset then you should use a cursor or do it in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: wow... i guess there are many more differences between MySQL and SQL Server than i thought. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @user2975318 You're quite welcome :) If you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it.

Comment: @user2975318 If you need help in translating in to MySQL consider to explain in plain words the logic of what that trigger should do.